# Calculate car acceleration from torque

Tags: torque, acceleration

I have data:

```
mass = 740 kg
wheel diameter = 670 mm
Rw = 0,335 m
power (max?) = 750 horsepower (551kW)
```

Now I would like to calculate car acceleration when throttle is max and speed in this moment = 100 km/h = 27,78 m/s

I calculate wheel RPM from this:

```
wheel speed(RPM) = v(km / h) * 25 / (3 * pi * r(m))
```

I get

```
WHEELrpm = 100 * 25 / (3 * 3,14 * 0,335) = 792
```

Next I calculate engine rpm:

```
RPMengine = RPMwheel * idifferential * igearbox * iclutch
```

where:

```
iidifferential  = 3,42
iclutch = 1
igearbox (gearbox ratio) = 2,55


RPMengine = 792 * 3,42 * 2,55 *1 = 6907
```

next I calculate torque from:

```
torque = (POWER * 5252) / rpm
```

I get

```
torque = (750 * 5252) / 6907 = 570
```

And now, apart from the resistance, I want to calculate drive force and acceleration.

I found this:

```
Fdrive = torque * gearboxRatio * iidifferential  * n / Rw
n - transmission efficiency (0,7?)
```

But I wonder if I can use it considering previous calculations. How to correctly calculate the acceleration now?

I try to base on this: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/22021
but I dont understand this formulas

Comment: acceleration is a change of velocity but you fixed that at 100km/h

Comment: I mean this is speed at this specific moment of time

Answer (score 1):

You are fine.  I'm not checking your work, but if you know engine torque, the using gear ratios you can calculate torque at the wheel.  Force at the road is torque divided by wheel radius, and then A = F/M